# Unmarshal mapped structure

Tags: go

First of all I have one structure:

```
type times map[time.Time]struct{}
```

I need to write for it `Marshal`/`Unmarshal` methods for json converting. I've wrote `MarshalJSON` method, but do not understand how to write `UnmarshalJSON` method.

```
func (ts times) keys() []time.Time {
    res := make([]time.Time, 0, len(ts))
    for key := range ts {
        res = append(res, key)
    }
    return res
}

func (ts times) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(ts.keys())
}

func (ts *times) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (error) {
    // ????
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decode json with the same way as you encoded(by taking only keys):

```
func (ts *times) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var t []time.Time

    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &t)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for _, v := range t {
        (*ts)[v] = struct{}{}
    }

    return nil
}
```

See: https://play.golang.org/p/0ViEBX_5iLw

But, I highly recommend to use a slice type, not a map.
The decoded output is an array, so the type should also be an array too.

Comment: Using a map makes the type a set, e.g. all values are unique. A slice wouldn't guarantee that.

Comment: @Peter, they're unmarshalled into a slice, then put into the map, at which point they're guaranteed unique, just as when they were marshalled. What's your concern?

Comment: @Adrian, I was commenting the last paragraph. Recommending to use a slice (outside the marshal/unmarshal methods) when set semantics are desired isn't appropriate.